# Removing from a string all the characthers included between two specific characters in Python

Tags: python, regex

What's a fast way in Python to take all the **characters** included between two specific **characters** out of a **string**?

Comment: Have you looked at the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) and regular expressions?

Comment: This is trivial. Next time try to search better...

Comment: Can you show us the resulting string that you expect?

Comment: @GalAbra This won't work

Comment: @MEE https://regex101.com/r/NBhBGb/1

Comment: @GalAbra you didn't posted the `\\` character in your original post

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression: `\(.*?\)`. Demo here: https://regexr.com/3jgmd

Then you can remove the part with this code:

```
import re
test_string = 'This is a string (here is a text to remove), and here is a text not to remove'
new_string = re.sub(r" \(.*?\)", "", test_string)
```

This regular expression (regex) will look for any text (without line break) in brackets prepended by a space

Answer (score 1):

You will most probably use a regular expression like

```
\s*\([^()]*\)\s*
```

for that (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8aIS6C/1)).
The expression removes everything in parentheses and surrounding whitespaces.

---

In `Python` this could be:

```
import re
test_string = 'This is a string (here is a text to remove), and here is a text not to remove'
new_string = re.sub(r'\s*\([^()]*\)\s*', '', test_string)
print(new_string)
# This is a string, and here is a text not to remove
```

---

However, for learning purposes, you could as well go with the builtin methods:

```
test_string = 'This is a string (here is a text to remove), and here is a text not to remove'
left = test_string.find('(')
right = test_string.find(')', left)

if left and right:
    new_string = test_string[:left] + test_string[right+1:]
    print(new_string)
    # This is a string , and here is a text not to remove
```

Problem with the latter: it does not account for multiple occurences and does not remove whitespaces but it is surely faster.

---

Executing this a 100k times each, the measurements yield:

```
0.578398942947 # regex solution
0.121736049652 # non-regex solution
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove all text in <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> you can use `findall()` method from `re` and remove them using `replace()`:

```
import re
test_string = 'This is a string (here is a text to remove), and here is a (second one) text not to remove'
remove = re.findall(r" \(.*?\)",test_string)
for r in remove:
    test_string = test_string.replace(r,'')
print(test_string)
#result: This is a string , and here is a  text not to remove
```